# how to download a file by using urlsession with requestbody

Tags: swift, url, sqlite, download

i need to request the server with the url and request body but the response will be a zip file i need to download the zip file and use it so i used the following method but i need to know how to save the file and reuse it
but getting the following error

Task <11E36FDA-1408-474D-B576-A222DEBA53B2>.<3> finished with error - code: -1005

```
     func performSyncRequest()
{
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let url = syncUrl.prepareSyncURL()
    var urlrequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlrequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlrequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let requestBody = syncUrl.prepareRequestBody()
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestBody, options: []) else { return }
    urlrequest.httpBody = httpBody
    do {
        let convertedString = String(data: httpBody, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("Sync Request Body: \(convertedString!)")
    }

    let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: urlrequest, completionHandler: { url,response,error in
        if error == nil {
            //some code

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at:url!, to: self.documentsUrl!)
                print(self.documentsUrl!)
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("error writing file \(self.documentsUrl!) : \(writeError)")
            }

        }
    })

    downloadTask.resume()
```

}

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that the downloaded file is copied to self.documentsURL. Can't you use that copy of the file?

Comment: no in documentsUrl their is no file

Comment: This program is similar to yours, and you will see the file copied: https://gist.github.com/pushkarnk/dabe290e9990abf47d34d626d2238fbb

Comment: in the above link they are using downloadTask with url but i am using downloadTask with urlrequest(RequestBody)

Comment: That shouldn't matter. See this: https://gist.github.com/pushkarnk/0d28d1f84439c0f21686a6096ef02ea8

Comment: Can you try running your program to download a smaller file? May be for  https://swift.org/LICENSE.txt ?

Comment: all other files are downloading

Comment: but it is showing the following error msgs  while trying to download zip file

Comment: TIC Read Status [2:0x604000362280]: 1:57  
Task <3F7F0C4E-BC1E-4CC0-B898-94EB4ED9D710>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [1:57])
Task <3F7F0C4E-BC1E-4CC0-B898-94EB4ED9D710>.<1> finished with error - code: -1005

Comment: Error code -1005 is `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`. Can you make sure your connection isn't failing midway? How big is the file you are downloading?

Comment: Another thing, URLSession writes the contents to a temporary file. In my case, the tmp file is under `/var/folders/hp/` Please make sure there's enough disk space.

Comment: i am trying to do it in stimulator and the size of the file is in kbs

Comment: and always the value of url is showing nil even after i got response

Comment: Is the zip file at a public URL?

Comment: public url with signature authentication

Comment: hmm, the url and response are nil because error is non-nil

Comment: response is also non -nil

Comment: OK, this is not a great suggestion - but can you try the same program using a delegate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640161/swift-how-to-know-when-the-file-is-successfully-download-from-url-using-filema?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: same errors again

Comment: The last thing I can suggest is to get onto Apple's slack (swiftpm.slack.com) and join the channel named #foundation You can talk to Apple developers there. May be they could help :-)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion

Comment: it is showing apple.com id is mandatory to join the swiftpmslack.com but i dont have any id with apple.com

Comment: Please use this URL to join: http://swift-package-manager.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the issue is while trying to download zip file their is no content length header so inorder to solve the issue i used the following code and it is working well

```
 urlrequest.addValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
```